# Android NDK: How to replace AAsset to work with files from external Storage for FFmpeg decoding

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk, oboe

I am using [Oboe's RhytmGame example](https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/RhythmGame) as a guideline to implement oboe and mp3 decoding using `FFmpeg` into my app. Since I am fairly new to the NDK and a C++ beginner I still struggle with some of the basic concepts I encounter. 
My problem: The example mentioned above only handles files from the asset folder, using the native implementation of Android's AssetManager.
Since I am looking to access files on external storage, I have to change this, but it is unclear to me how to do that.

This is where I am stuck:
I have a `FFmpegExtractor` class that calls this method in `FFmpeg's avio.h`:

```
 * Allocate and initialize an AVIOContext for buffered I/O. It must be later
 * freed with avio_context_free().
 *
 * @param buffer Memory block for input/output operations via AVIOContext.
 *        The buffer must be allocated with av_malloc() and friends.
 *        It may be freed and replaced with a new buffer by libavformat.
 *        AVIOContext.buffer holds the buffer currently in use,
 *        which must be later freed with av_free().
 * @param buffer_size The buffer size is very important for performance.
 *        For protocols with fixed blocksize it should be set to this blocksize.
 *        For others a typical size is a cache page, e.g. 4kb.
 * @param write_flag Set to 1 if the buffer should be writable, 0 otherwise.
 * @param opaque An opaque pointer to user-specific data.
 * @param read_packet  A function for refilling the buffer, may be NULL.
 *                     For stream protocols, must never return 0 but rather
 *                     a proper AVERROR code.
 * @param write_packet A function for writing the buffer contents, may be NULL.
 *        The function may not change the input buffers content.
 * @param seek A function for seeking to specified byte position, may be NULL.
 *
 * @return Allocated AVIOContext or NULL on failure.
 */
AVIOContext *avio_alloc_context(
                  unsigned char *buffer,
                  int buffer_size,
                  int write_flag,
                  void *opaque,
                  int (*read_packet)(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size),
                  int (*write_packet)(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size),
                  int64_t (*seek)(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence));
```

The call is made here:

```
bool FFMpegExtractor::createAVIOContext(AAsset *asset, uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t bufferSize,
                                        AVIOContext **avioContext) {

    constexpr int isBufferWriteable = 0;

    *avioContext = avio_alloc_context(
            buffer, // internal buffer for FFmpeg to use
            bufferSize, // For optimal decoding speed this should be the protocol block size
            isBufferWriteable,
            asset, // Will be passed to our callback functions as a (void *)
            read, // Read callback function
            nullptr, // Write callback function (not used)
            seek); // Seek callback function

    if (*avioContext == nullptr){
        LOGE("Failed to create AVIO context");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am looking to replace the `asset`, `read` and `seek` arguments so that I can use files from storage instead of AAsset objects.

This is the `read` callback passed above:

```
int read(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int buf_size) {

    auto asset = (AAsset *) opaque;
    int bytesRead = AAsset_read(asset, buf, (size_t)buf_size);
    return bytesRead;
}
```

And this is the `seek`callback:

```
int64_t seek(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence){

    auto asset = (AAsset*)opaque;

    // See https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/avio_8h.html#a427ff2a881637b47ee7d7f9e368be63f
    if (whence == AVSEEK_SIZE) return AAsset_getLength(asset);
    if (AAsset_seek(asset, offset, whence) == -1){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have tried just replacing AAsset with FILE, but of course that doesn't do it. I know how to open and read files, but it is unclear to me if that is what's expected here, and how I can translate the methods in AAsset to operations that return the desired values for files in storage. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

*Edit:* As it couldn't fit down there here is the code block mentioned in my reply to @BrianChen's helpful comments:

```
bool FFMpegExtractor::openAVFormatContext(AVFormatContext *avFormatContext) {

    int result = avformat_open_input(&avFormatContext,
                                     "", /* URL is left empty because we're providing our own I/O */
                                     nullptr /* AVInputFormat *fmt */,
                                     nullptr /* AVDictionary **options */
    );
```

Unfortunately `avformat_open_input()` produces a
`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 23767, pid 23513`

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as using AAsset.

```cpp
// wrapper class for file stream 
class  MediaSource {
public:
    MediaSource() {
    }
    ~MediaSource() {
        source.close();
    }
    void open(const string& filePath) {
        source.open(filePath, ios::in | ios::binary);
    }
    int read(uint8_t *buffer, int buf_size) {
        // read data to buffer
        source.read((char *)buffer, buf_size)
        // return how many bytes were read
        return source.gcount();
    }
    int64_t seek(int64_t offset, int whence) {
        if (whence == AVSEEK_SIZE) {
            // FFmpeg needs file size.
            int oldPos = source.tellg();
            source.seekg(0,ios::end);
            int64_t length = source.tellg();
            // seek to old pos
            source.seekg(oldPos);
            return length;
        } else if (whence == SEEK_SET) {
            // set pos to offset
            source.seekg(offset);
        } else if (whence == SEEK_CUR) {
            // add offset to pos
            source.seekg(offset, ios::cur);
        } else {
            // do not support other flags, return -1
            return -1;
        }
        // return current pos
        return source.tellg();
    }
private:
    ifstream source;
};

// If FFmpeg needs to read the file, it will call this function.
// We need to fill the buffer with file's data.
int read(void *opaque, uint8_t *buffer, int buf_size) {
    MediaSource *source = (MediaSource *)opaque;
    return source->read(buffer, buf_size);
}

// If FFmpeg needs to seek in the file, it will call this function.
// We need to change the read pos.
int64_t seek(void *opaque, int64_t offset, int whence) {
    MediaSource *source = (MediaSource *)opaque;
    return source->seek(offset, whence);
}

// add MediaSource to class FFMpegExtractor
class FFMpegExtractor {
private:
    // add this line to declare of class FFMpegExtractor
    MediaSource* mSource;
};

FFMpegExtractor::FFMpegExtractor() {
    // add this line in constructor, new a instance
    mSource = new MediaSource;
}

FFMpegExtractor::~FFMpegExtractor() {
    // add this line in destructor, release instance
    delete mSource;
}

bool FFMpegExtractor::createAVIOContext(const string& filePath, uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t bufferSize,
                                        AVIOContext **avioContext) {

    mSource.open(filePath);
    constexpr int isBufferWriteable = 0;

    *avioContext = avio_alloc_context(
            buffer, // internal buffer for FFmpeg to use
            bufferSize, // For optimal decoding speed this should be the protocol block size
            isBufferWriteable,
            mSource, // Will be passed to our callback functions as a (void *)
            read, // Read callback function
            nullptr, // Write callback function (not used)
            seek); // Seek callback function

    if (*avioContext == nullptr){
        LOGE("Failed to create AVIO context");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this helps a lot. Unfortunately there seem to be some problems with this, maybe you can help me out here?  
1. you ignore `opaque` completely. Isn't that where I have to read from and seek in?  
2. I have to pass my source to `avio_alloc_context()` as a void*. IDE tells me that `ifstream`is icompatible. How can I get from my file I have the path to to something I can pass into here?  
3. the read() function doesn't work because source.read() expects the buffer passed to it to be a `char*` and not a `uint8_t`. What can I do about this?

Comment: I edit the answer. 1. You can pass a `MediaSource` to `avio_alloc_context()`. Before that, you should create a `MediaSource` with the file path. 3. You can convert `uint8_t *` to `char *`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems to do the trick, unfortunately now I get a SIGSEV crash, and I don't really know how to fix that.  
So I created the `MediaSource*` I pass to `createAVIOContext()` like this: `    MediaSource source(filepath);
    MediaSource* source_ptr = &source;` 
Not sure if that is correct. Anyway, the error happens when the created context is opened (I'll add the code to the question, it doesn't fit the comment...
Any idea how I can solve this? The whole pointers and memory allocation is petty much a mystery to me...

Comment: You have to new a MediaSource instance or save a MediaSource instance as member variable of FFMpegExtractor. A local variable will be released when it leaves it’s scope.

Comment: I know this is a beginner issue, but could you please point me to how I would do that correctly? I don't seem to get this correctly (coming from Java, things are quite different for me here)

Comment: With the saved instance I'm still getting the same crash, when debugging I can see that both `read()`and `seek()`get called multiple times, but then it crashes.I don't know if that has at all to do with the code you provided or if this now is a different issue...

Comment: I think that is a different issue, you should provide the crash stack. Is that crash in `read` or `seek` function?

Comment: The crash happens while `read()`is executed.
This is all I get with ndk-stack:

`********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/bonito/bonito:9/PQ3B.190605.006/5560048:user/release-keys'
#00 0x0000000000017d48 /data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-OF8A7i0wtH_VjboPCcSK0g==/lib/arm64/libavutil.so (av_dict_free+8)
                                                                                                       ??
                                                                                                       ??:0:0
`

Comment: I run my program in Android, it works. I think you have other problems.

Comment: I still haven't figured it out unfortunately. But one thing came to my mind:
Doesn't this: 
`int read(uint8_t *buffer, int buf_size) {
        // read data to buffer
        source.read((char *)buffer, buf_size)
        // return how many bytes were read
        return source.gcount();
    }`
always return the size of the source instead of the read bytes? Or am I completely wrong?